# Android theme not used in library project

Tags: java, android, android-theme

I am building a library project which returns `Views` based on a user request. However the `Views` I create in the library project do not use the theme I use in my application.

For example if the library project returns a `Fragment` which has an `EditText` in it, then the `EditText` will not use the AppCompat theme even though the app is using it.

Here is the relevant part of the base class I use to inflate the `Views` in the library project:

```
public abstract class AbsInputFieldViewController<T extends AbsInputField> {

    protected Context getContext(){
        return mFragment.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    }

    protected LayoutInflater getInflater(){
        return (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public abstract View getView(AbsInputField field, Fragment fragment);
}
```

`getView()` is implemented in a few sub classes and it uses the `LayoutInflater` from `getInflater()` to inflate a `View` instance from a layout xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting the `LayoutInflater` with `getSystemService()`. If you want the `LayoutInflater` to use a specific theme you have to create it from a `Context` which is using that theme. Usually that would be the `Context` from an `Activity` or from your `Application`. Try this instead:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```